MPI_Isend and MPI_Waitall do not work well
I have implemented mpi_isend and mpi_waitwall in order to
send the messages of each cpu to its corresponding neighbours.
After mpi_Isend, I call mpi_waitall in order to guarantee the
messages have been sent away from each cpu:
void myisend()
{

    int numcpuneibs{commute_->numcpuneibs()}; 
    MPI_Request req[numcpuneibs];
    MPI_Status  status[numcpuneibs];

    for(int neib=0; neib<numcpuneibs; neib++)
    {
        MPI_Isend(bndgridfunc_->sendptr(neib),
                  bndgridfunc_->numbndptsatneib(neib),
                  MPI_DOUBLE,
                  commute_->neighbor(neib),                  
                  0,
                  commute_->comm(),
                  &req[neib]
                 );  
    }

    
    MPI_Waitall(numcpuneibs,
                req,
                status
}

However, I can only sent a very small amount of data. I have
checked the memory on the computer. There are enough memory
on the computer.
If I comment out MPI_Waitall.  the program can finish. But I am
not sure if the messages have been sent completely without caling mpi_waitall.
Can anyone have some experience with this?

You should always assume MPI_Send() will block until a matching receive is posted, otherwise your program is invalid w.r.t. the MPI standard. In this case, MPI_Waitall() following MPI_Isend() can block if no matching receive has previously been posted.

Here MPI_Waitall() returns when the send buffers can be overwritten. It does not mean the message has been sent, and does not force any message to be sent.

Thanks.  I have just tried to add MPI_IRecv in order to pair the MPI_Isend.  But it seems not to work:

you need to post all MPI_Isend(), then all MPI_Irecv() and then MPI_Waitall() on both send and receive requests. If you are still stuck after that, trim your code down to a [mcve].

Thanks alot.  I now call  MPI_Isend, MPI_IRecv, MPI_Waitall for isend requests, and MPI_Waitall for irecv requests instead of calling MPI_Waitall after isend and after irecv.  It starts to work.  This is bit confusing for me why the other way does not works well: Call ISend, then Waitall until the messages are sent out;  afterwards call Irecv, then Waitall until the messages are received. This seems to me follow the streamline of communications.  I might totally misunderstand the communication methods using MPI.

you misunderstand the semantic of MPI_Wait() following MPI_Isend(), see my second comment.

Thanks a lot. I have red your second comment. It seems I still could not get the answer. Does "the send buffers can be overwitten" means the message has been sent? Otherwise, how can we overwrite the send buffers if the messages are still in the buffers?  This is really confusing for me, as a new mpi user. Many thanks.

It does not mean the message has been sent. For example, the MPI library can copy it to an other buffer in order to send it later.

OK. But does calling "MPI_Isend, MPI_IRecv, MPI_Waitall for isend/irecv requests" mean the messages have been sent out from the send buffer and have been received in the recv buffers. Therefore each cpu can use the data in the recv buffers and continue the computations.  Or shall we  call some other MPI routines in order to make sure this step is done?  Another issue is shall we  immediately copy the data from recv buffer to some memory for late usage, otherwise the data might be overwritten? Or the data remains in the recv buffer within its corresponding function scope we can directly use?

It means that on that given process all the data has been received from all the peers, and all the send buffers can be overwritten. Unless the peer has completed MPI_Waitall() you cannot assume any data has been sent. The data won't be magically overwritten into the receive buffers as long as you do not call MPI_Irecv() with the same receive buffer.

Thanks a lot.  This is really a great help!
